# Installshield read .properties file

Tags: file, installshield, installscript

I'm new to installshield and i need to read a .properties file prior to install. 
Because the wizard name, headers are declared in that.
The structure is like this: install.wizard.name="MyApp".

First is this possible in installshield? And second how do you do it?

thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [ListReadFromFile](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield16helplib/mergedProjects/installshield16langref/LangrefListReadFromFile.htm)  function.

There is an example on that page.  Basically you need to read the file into a list, iterate through the list and do string parsing to figure out the value of the key you care about.

Comment: And this works with the .properties extension? Because all the examples are with a .bat extension file

Comment: A text file is a text file, is it not?

Comment: I managed to find a string for example "test" in my file. But now i'm struggeling to find for example install.wizard.name=MyApp. I only can enter install.wizard.name in to the ListFindString methode because the rest is not always the same. Can you use wildcards for example :ListFindString(list,"install.wizard.name*") ?

Comment: Are you familiar with looping?  You call ListGetFirstString then StrGetTokens to split your key from your value.  If the key is a match you get the value and exit.  Otherwise you call ListGetNextString and repeat the process until you find what you are looking for or reach the end of the list.